# Glassfish administration scripting

Tags: scripting, glassfish, administration

I am trying to move a web application that currently runs on WebSphere 6.1 application server over Glassfish 3.X. I currently have a set of WebSphere jacl files that configure an instance of a WAS for my web application (data sources, queues, etc.) and a .bat and a .sh file that execute the jacl files (I think via wsadmin). I develop on a WAS instance on my Windows PC and the software is tested on a WAS instance installed on a Solaris test machine.

Is there the equivalent concept for Glassfish?

That is, does Glassfish have a concept of a platform independent administration scripting language like WebSphere jacl/jython that can be executed from a call from a Windows .bat file or a Unix .sh file?

I'm relatively new to web development and so I may have made some conceptual mistakes and you may also have to fill in some gaps in my question.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can feed a configuration script to asadmin, that contains asadmin subcommands like deploy and create-jdbc-resource, etc...

The 'language' does not have any real flow-of-control or looping constructs, so you would need to flatten those types of things out of the script that would get called by your dot-bat or dot-sh.

If you are really leveraging jacl/jython this might not be possible... but if you aren't putting these interpreters through their paces, the asadmin 'language' may be rich enough for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When you say "You can feed a configuration script to asadmin", do you know of any online resources that describe exactly how to run a script using asadmin and also provide help on the 'language' you talk about. Thanks again.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19879-01/820-4335/gcode/index.html and http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/giobi.html.  The key word is multimode.  The language is just the available asadmin commands.

Comment: Thanks vkraemer. I'll take a look at that multimode subcommand and see how far I get.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, take at a look at the "asadmin" command.  It should be able to configure most anything you need from a script.

Comment: I need more than just "asadmin". I want to write the app server configuration logic in a platform neutral scripting language (as you can do with WebSphere jacl/jython files). Then I want to do something like call "asadmin <config_script_file_name>" from my .bat/.sh files. asadmin would run the script and configure the app server. Without the platform neutral script file, I have to implement the config logic directly in both the .bat/.sh files. This duplication of logic would be a maintenance headache. Maybe I could use Perl and forget about Unix and Windows scripts altogether.

Comment: It sounds like you might want to write your configuration in Java and use the Glassfish admin API instead of running asadmin from a script.  That avoids needing anything else on the platform besides java and glassfish.  http://javadoc.glassfish.org/v3/apidoc/org/glassfish/api/admin/package-tree.html